# Какой ORM выбрать для проектов в SQL Alchemy?

Tags: sqlalchemy

Столкнулся с двумя версиями одного ORM в SQL Alchemy.
Один строит запросы вида:

```
smtp = select(User).where(User.id == 1)
    user = session.execute(smtp).all()
```

Второй строит запросы вида:

```
product = db.query(Product).get(product_id)
```

В самой документации помечено, что второй - устаревший.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Означает ли это, что все новые проекты с sql alchemy откажутся от использования ORM Query?

Comment: Коротко, если Legacy - то, скорее всего, в какой-то момент откажутся.